# Building Workspace has ecountered error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

```
An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
jzentry == 0,
jzfile = 127476560,
total = 28,
name = C:\Users\amar.agarwal5\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-antrun-plugin\1.6\maven-antrun-plugin-1.6.jar,
i = 1,
message = null
```

what should i do??
I have just downloaded the hibernate tools from marketplace and after that I am getting this error on restart

Comment: Can you check if you have accidently installed two versions of `maven-antrun-plugin-1.6.jar` in your `C:\Users\amar.agarwal5\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-antrun-plugin\1.6`?